# How to convert arbitrary type to string, without adding extra quotes to strings?

Tags: haskell

I want to define a function which converts to strings, like the following 'toString':

```
toString 1 = "1"
toString True = "True"
toString "1" = "1"
```

Note that 'show' does not do this. By contrast it does the following:

```
show 1 = "1"
show True = "True"
show "1" = "\"1\""
```

That is, it adds extra quotes around strings. In this case I don't want to add extra quotes if I already have a string.

I'm considering using something like:

```
import Data.Typeable

toString a :: (Show a) => a -> String
toString a
  | typeOf a == typeOf "" = a
  | otherwise = show a
```

Are there any pitfalls in doing such a weird type-based conditional? Is there some built-in Haskell function that would be better to use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of ad-hoc polymorphism is permitted through type-classes. However, they will have to be overlapping since you want a catch all case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecideableInstances #-}

class Print a where
  makeString :: a -> String

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Print String where
  makeString s = s

instance Show a => Print a where
  makeString x = show x
```

---

Then, your function is `makeString :: Print a => a -> String` and it has an instance for everything that has a `Show` instance. To have the second instance, you need `FlexibleInstances` (the instance head is not of the usual form) and `UndecideableInstances` (since the constraint is as general as the instance head, GHC can't be sure that it won't fall into an infinite loop trying to solve these constraints).

Answer (score 5):

If you want something like Alec's approach without overlapping instances, you can get it with a type family.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses, ScopedTypeVariables, UndecidableInstances, FlexibleInstances, DataKinds, ... whatever else GHC tells you it needs #-}

import Data.Text (Text, unpack)
import Data.Proxy

class Print a where
  makeString :: a -> String

data Name = NString | NText | NShow
type family Choose a where
  Choose [Char] = 'NString
  Choose Text = 'NText
  Choose _ = 'NShow

class Print' (n :: Name) a where
  makeString' :: proxy n -> a -> String

instance (Choose a ~ n, Print' n a) => Print a where
  makeString = makeString' (Proxy :: Proxy n)

instance a ~ String => Print' 'NString a where
  makeString' _ = id

instance a ~ Text => Print' 'NText a where
  makeString' _ = unpack

instance Show a => Print' 'NShow a where
  makeString' _ = show
```

Answer (score 5):

Expanding the OP solution attempt into a working one:

```
import Data.Typeable

toString :: (Show a, Typeable a) => a -> String
toString x = case cast x of
   Just y  -> y
   Nothing -> show x
```

Comment: This only works if x is `String`. For example, if x is `Text`, then it still adds the quote